# Definition of $\tilde{H}_n(X,A)$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence, natural-transformations

My question arises from the following sentence of Hatcher's book p.118, in particular

[image]

I do understand that $\tilde{H}_n(X,A)$ is defined to be $H_n(X,A)$ if $n \ne 0$. There is a canonical way to define the reduced homology in order to have, given a long exact sequence of complex

$$0 \longrightarrow C_n(A) \longrightarrow C_n(X) \longrightarrow C_n(X,A) \longrightarrow 0$$

A natural long exact sequence of the pair $(X,A)$ for the reduced relative homology ? i.e

$$\cdots \longrightarrow \tilde{H}_n(A) \longrightarrow  \tilde{H}_n(X) \longrightarrow H_n(X,A) \longrightarrow \tilde{H}_{n-1}(A) \longrightarrow \cdots$$

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373347/homology-and-reduced-homology-coincide-on-non-trivial-pair) that doesn't solve the problem since the definition seems implicit.

Comment: Does this not occur when we simply define the reduced homology as the homology of the augmented chain complex?

Comment: @memerson So the natural exact sequence for the relative "standard" homology of $(X,A)$, is the same since is transporded under this isomorphism ?

Comment: @memerson I think I don't get how to define the $0-$level $\tilde{H}_0(A) \longrightarrow \tilde{H}_0(X) \longrightarrow H_0(X,A) \longrightarrow 0$ since the other terms are equal to the non relative reduced version

Comment: There are two different steps in what is going on. First, $\tilde H_n(X,A) = H_n(X,A)$. Not just isomorphic. They are precisely equal as sets. They are identical in every possible way. Second, any short exact sequence of chain complexes gives rise to a natural long exact sequence in homology, so the short exact sequence of augmented chain complexes gives rise to a natural long exact sequence in reduced homology. But because $\tilde H(X,A) = H(X,A)$ we can put this in the exact sequence and preserve exactness and naturality.

Comment: @memerson Thanks, I do understand the pattern now. I'm interested in the sentence (see also my comment under Paul Frost's answer) "so the short exact sequence of augmented chain complexes gives rise to a natural long exact sequence in reduced homology". Could you link or explain reference of this ?

Comment: I'm sure I could find a reference if you need one, but this happens because an augmented chain complex is still just a chain complex. So the same exact proof for the unaugmented version goes through. If the fact that we now have things in degree -1 is bothering you, we can simply reindex the chain complex, get our long exact sequence and then change the indices back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reduced homology groups of spaces $X$ and pairs $(X,A)$ are defined as the homology groups of the *augmented chain complexes* $\tilde C_*(X)$ and $\tilde C_*(X,A)$. For details see my answer to [Suppose that $X$ is a topological space and $x_0\in X$. Prove that $\widetilde{H_n}(X)=H_n(X,x_0)$ for all $n\geq 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3281300) Note that $X = \emptyset$ plays a somewhat strange role in this context since formally $\tilde H_{-1}(\emptyset) = \mathbb Z$. Therefore one usually excludes the case $X = \emptyset$ when working with reduced homology. But note that *formally* everything works well even if we allow $X = \emptyset$.

In fact for any pair $(X,A)$ we obtain a short exact sequence of chain complexes
$$0 \to \tilde C_*(A) \to \tilde C_*(X) \to \tilde C_*(X,A) \to 0 .$$
But **each** short exact sequence of chain complexes
$$0 \to R \to S \to T \to 0$$
gives a long exact sequence of homology groups
$$ \dots \to H_n(R) \to H_n(S) \to H_n(T) \stackrel{\partial}{\to} H_{n-1}(R) \to \dots$$
This results in the natural long exact reduced homology sequence of the pair $(X,A)$.

From the definitions of $\tilde C_*(X)$ and $\tilde C_*(X,A)$ we see that

1. $\tilde H_n(X) = H_n(X)$ for $n > 0$
2. $\tilde H_n(X,A) = H_n(X,A)$ for all $n$.
3. $H_0(X) \approx \tilde H_0(X) \oplus \mathbb  Z $

The long exact reduced homology sequence of a pair $(X,A)$ with $A \ne \emptyset$ is therefore identical with the long exact unreduced homology sequence except at the final terms:
$$\dots \to H_1(A) \to H_1(X) \to H_1(X,A) \to \tilde H_0(A) \to \tilde H_0(X) \to H_0(X,A) \to 0$$

Also have a look at my answer to [Clarification about reduced Homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3666124).

Comment: In 3. did you mean $n = 0$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, my question was more addressed in understanding from where and the naturality of the long exact sequence for reduced homology you told me [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070339/tildeh-nx-cup-ca-simeq-h-nx-a) comes from

Comment: @jacopoburelli Yes, in 3. I had a typo. The exactness of the long homology sequence (for any short exact sequence of chain complexes) is a purely algbraic result. See Hatcher p. 116.